# How to send notification between two android devices

Tags: android

I have App "A" in android device "A" and i have the App "b" in android device "B" .I want to send notification from device "A" to device "B"with her number phone

Comment: how i can send an SMS

Comment: Did you hear of a tool called [Google](https://www.google.it/#q=android%20send%20sms%20intent)?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for Google Cloud Messaging service. Refer to this link for details.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

For sending messages in push notification. The below link is useful.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notification that is targeted by a phone number. Take a look on Parse.com - [Android push guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) You can save a phone number in `ParseInstallation` and then target this installation:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("phone", "1234567890");
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```