# Push notifications between ANDROID devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, server

I am trying to figure out how to push a received notifications from one android device to another one. Example: someone sends you a message on your android phone. You receive a notification on your watch that this happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382900/how-to-send-notification-between-two-android-devices

Comment: Best way would be through Parse or any other BaaS indeed, but I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want is to receive a notification on the android watch when you receive a notification on the phone is that right?

Well this happens automatically so if you don't want to add anything extra or custom to a notification you don't have to do anything.

If you want to produce custom notification for wearable with specific actions, icons or other thing you need to follow the android guidelines at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

You might need to intercept the notification you receive on the phone and handle it like this and then send it again to both phone and watch.

Comment: I know that happens in a Android Phone+ Android Wear Smartwatch "pair". But what if the smartwatch runs Android as an OS, exactly like the phone? How can I create this bond that already exists between a phone and Android Wear Device? Imagine using two Android Phones if you can't imagine having a smartwatch running Android as an OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is solely for communication between Android devices that each have Google Play Services installed and valid registration IDs:

You will need a bidirectional implementation of GCM, one that allows devices to both receive and send messages to the server. The HTTP GCM server setup will only allow downstream communication (server -> device). For your needs you can use the [XMPP implementation of GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html).